# New Computer Memory Management BSOD

Tags: memory, windows-10, motherboard, bsod

I just built my first computer and I'm getting a lot of blue screens. Mostly memory_management errors, but also  irql_not_less_or_equal and system_service_exception errors. I took both ram out and tested them in different sockets individually and still getting errors.  Currently I'm running memtest86+ and so far no errors.

cpu: intel i7 6700k
gpu: nvidia gtx 970
motherboard: asrock z170 pro4
ram : 2 8gb hyperx furry ddr4
os: windows 10

This is the Who Crashed log, originally the time on the computer was off so the times are a little screwed up, [From pastebin:- Crash dump directory: C:\Windows\Minidump](http://pastebin.com/uyKrXhne)

Anyone have any advice? It's really depressing that my first diy computer is causing me so much grief... Thanks.

Comment: This seems to indicate driver/software issues. Looks like you tried the obvious.  I'd also update drivers for *everything*, especially the video card - windows 10 is terrible about stomping over nvidia drivers. If this fails, perhaps try a fresh install of windows and see what happens. Since this errors are software related, what're you doing when this happens? Any common software?

Comment: how about diff hdd, diff cable, diff sata port, new windows installation. Maybe something stable win7 is ok at least for a test. That eliminates tons of stuff. No drivers other than the min required. eg chipset driver. See how it goes then if that goes no errors, then try to change to more like what you have now and see when the errors come and isolate the problem, if you feel the need.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I *think* I installed all the drivers. Motherboard drivers from the included cd as well as bios update, nvidia driver from the site. Originally I thought it was the windows install so this is the second install. Pretty much crashes using everything, but especially when trying windows update.

Comment: @barlop I can switch the sata port, and if I can't find the problem after another pass on memtest I'll try installing win7 on a HDD, currently win10 is installed on a SSD.

Comment: included cd drivers are older. try the ones from the asrock site.

Comment: I hate when people post "me too" posts but... me too. i7 6700k, Z170, GTX 970, 4x8GB DDR4. Should say I doubt it's a SATA (or any storage) related problem. When those happen, Windows tends to be unable to save a crash dump in the first place.

Comment: u dont need to install every driver on the cd if testing for what causes a crash. You could try with as few drivers as possible n see if it crashes. then u know its not crashing from a driver. If no crash then thats progress

Comment: we need the real dmp files and not such useless text files ..

Answer (score 0):

Besides the GPU (GTX960) i have the same Setup as you have and until last week i had the same annoying bluescreens with mem.management....

I was short before changing the Mainboard because there were so many different Bluescreens from different components. I'm glad i didn't.

What i did to fix the problem was to download and run the "App Shop" program which ASRock provides on their site. With this program i **updated my BIOS(UEFI)** and since then i had no bluescreens no matter how long and intense the PC was running.

[Link to Download](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z170%20Pro4/?cat=Download&os=Win1064)

I hope this also helps in your case!

Answer (score 0):

This is most than defiantly a Driver issue.

First, **Update your UEFI** (BIOS) by referring to the manufacturers website, downloading the latest and installing.

Secondly, **Update all of your drivers** by going to there respective manufacturer website and ensure you are downloading the Windows 10 (32 or 64bit respectively) drivers.

Also, Perform a windows update afterwards just to ensure everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem for a long time. I damn near killed myself trying to fix it. I have a 6600k and ASROCK z170 extreme6. Basically, my motherboard automatically clocked my RAM too low. Check the speed, timing, and voltage of your RAM in your BIOS and make sure it corresponds with the actual specs of the RAM. Mine was clocked at 2133 when my RAM was marketed at 2400. This fixed the problem instantly.

Edit: By the way, even running memory test with the issue I had showed that there was nothing wrong, but it was clearly a memory issue.